# VB.NET Class Instances

Tags: vb.net, class

I'm writing a class library and I'm hoping I can spare the user (the one who will be using this library) from using the New keyword.  Coding on the user's part will look something like this:

```
Dim result As Integer = MyLibrary.MyObject.Sum(1,2)
```

This is a simplified example, but you get the idea.  The difficult part is MyObject needs to be instantiated because it has it's own private properties to keep track.

It's like a context for MyLibrary is created for the user.  Is this doable?

Comment: What's wrong with the `New` keyword?

Comment: You're looking for a singleton. Now that you know what it's called, you can Google for it. Probably turn up a bunch of SO questions already asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the singleton pattern:

```
Public Class MyLibrary
    Private _MyObject As MyLibrary
    Public ReadOnly Property MyObject As MyLibrary
        Get
            If _MyObject Is Nothing Then
                _MyObject = New MyLibrary()
            End If

            Return _MyObject
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Sum(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
        Return a + b
    End Function
End Class
```

Or you use the keyword `Shared` (in c# it is `static`):

```
Namespace MyLibrary
    Public Class MyObject
        Public Shared Function Sum(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
            Return a + b
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Or, in VB.NET you can use a `Module` instead of a class:

```
Namespace MyLibrary
    Public Module MyObject
        Public Function Sum(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
            Return a + b
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```